# Bit shifting (error: shift amount is larger than type size in bits)

Tags: ios, swift

***Hi everyone,***

I am fairly new to Swift and I got a problem, I am trying to implement the [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) in Swift to generate a Time-Based One-Time Password but I have trouble with array types and bit shifting :

```
    let Input:[UInt8] = [UInt8](hash.base32DecodedString()!.utf8)
    
        do {
    
        let ouput = try HMAC(key: Input, variant: .sha1).authenticate(self.toByteArray(self.currentTimeMillis()))
        
    let offset = Int(ouput[ouput.count - 1]) & 0x0f
        
_ = (ouput[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) | (ouput[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) | (ouput[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) | (ouput[offset + 3] & 0xff)

          } catch { }
```

> **I get this error:**
> **error: shift amount is larger than type size in bits**

My guess is that output[] doesn't have the right type for the bit shifting amount but I can't find the right one.

Comment: You can think of `s << n` as `s * 2**n`. `UInt16` has a max value of `65535` which is `(1 << 16) - 1`. Considering this, you can't have a `UInt16` with a `<< 24` as that is much larger than `(1 << 16) - 1`.

Comment: Why are you trying to shift a 16 bit type by 24 bits?

Comment: Don't confuse things by editing changing the actual code. Show the *actual* type of `ouput` (or `output`).

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to change that before sending my code, I'm using that lib to get the output -> https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: This is a previously solved problem: https://github.com/mattrubin/OneTimePassword So why not use an existing library?